# Angular - mat-slide-toggle change color

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I can't seem to find how to change my toggle's color..

HTML:

```
<td data-label="Actief" *ngIf="user.enabled">
    <mat-slide-toggle></mat-slide-toggle>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(50, 170, 118);
    /*replace with your color*/
}

::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: rgb(113, 226, 147);
    /*replace with your color*/
}
```

I have searched for various sources but my toggle is just pink. I applied the css-styles like both chatGPT and other stackoverflow users suggested in various posts. The color is never changed.

I want it to be green when active and red when inactive.

Right now it is still like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using Angular Material 15, the classes have changed in version 15, try the below code with the updated class names

```css
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-slide-toggle.mat-mdc-slide-toggle-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mdc-switch__shadow {
  background-color: rgb(50, 170, 118);
  /*replace with your color*/
}

::ng-deep .mat-mdc-slide-toggle.mat-mdc-slide-toggle-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mdc-switch__track::after {
  background-color: rgb(113, 226, 147) !important;
  /*replace with your color*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked very smoothly, Can we decrease the size of it?

Answer (score 0):

For the track color and the color of the icon within the thumb (e.g. the checkmark if it's selected) you can also locally overload the used CSS variables, so you don't have to use ng-deep:

```
.mat-mdc-slide-toggle .mdc-form-field .mdc-switch {
  --mdc-switch-selected-track-color: green;
  --mdc-switch-unselected-track-color: gray;

  --mdc-switch-selected-icon-color: yellow;
  --mdc-switch-unlected-icon-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

good practice is to do in your app good styling - doing it like primary variables. So if you want to do - do it throw changing color of primary colors in your  _variables.scss like example.There it can be described:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/ .
I have such experience - like years ago - and it hard to understand what is going on in project that you should change every time color in css files - different and none linked in structure. One place better for concentrating.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).